# How to submit both text and images at the same time using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to upload an image to a mysql database using php. The image should be inserted to the same row as the user. So, in my not-so-good attempt to do this, i have created a textbox and an upload form, so when the user enters his name on the textbox and uploaded an image they will be saved at the same time. The problem here is that I'm not quite sure if the method I've tried is right. well, I'm not really good in php to begin with. any help will do!

here is my form:

```
<?php

require('admin.config.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $path = "/home/********/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";

    if($image_name==''){
    echo "Don't just click! select an image please .";
    exit();
    }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $path);
    $mysql_path = $path."/".$image_name;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `admin`(`admin_image1`,`path1`) VALUES ('$image_name','$mysql_path') where username = :user";

    $query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':image_name' => $image_name,
        ':mysql_path' => $path,
        );

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't Upload Image!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Image Uploaded Succesfully!";
    echo json_encode($response);
   }
    }   
    ?>

<form action="adminProfilePic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
<input type="file" name="image" >

<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

~also, I'm not quite sure if my query_params is correct.

Comment: well, i think I have made an attempt to put a textbox there named username.

Comment: I did a quick and successful test, but I am questioning `where username = :user` why are you using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.:** There are 3 different types. 2 of which are different types of `INSERT`'s and one `UPDATE`.

I used `user` as the column name, so you may want to either keep it, or adjust it.

**I successfully tested this** and do read throughout the code for additional comments.

Assuming DB variable in `admin.config.inc.php` is set to `$db` - If not, then you will need to modify the variable to suit/match,

As a regular `INSERT` use the following (An `UPDATE` version follows)

```
<?php
require('admin.config.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $path = "/home/********/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";

    if($image_name==''){
    echo "Don't just click! select an image please .";
    exit();
    }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $path);
    $mysql_path = $path."/".$image_name;

// I am unsure of this line and how you are using it, so the UPDATE version follows.
// Test with the line below that for now
//  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `admin_test_so` (`admin_image1`,`path1`) VALUES (:image_name,:mysql_path) where username = :user");

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `admin_test_so` (`admin_image1`,`path1`) VALUES (:image_name,:mysql_path)");

    try {

 $stmt->execute(array(
  ':image_name' => $image_name,
  ':mysql_path' => $path

    ));

}
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't Upload Image!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Image Uploaded Succesfully!";
    echo json_encode($response);

/* my own tests to show what is set or not */
/*
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($image_name);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($path);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_POST['username']);
*/

   }
    }   
?>
```

### As a `UPDATE` type, use the following:

This will work with your `WHERE` clause, which will update a row if the user's name exists.

Again, assuming DB variable is set to `$db`

```
<?php
require('admin.config.inc.php');

$username=$_POST['username'];

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $path = "/home/********/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";

    if($image_name==''){
    echo "Don't just click! select an image please .";
    exit();
    }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $path);
    $mysql_path = $path."/".$image_name;

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `admin_test_so` set admin_image1=:image_name, path1=:image_name where user = :user");

// update test_table set value=:value, value0=:value0 where value=:value

    try {

 $stmt->execute(array(
  ':user' => $username,
  ':image_name' => $image_name,
  ':mysql_path' => $path

    ));

}
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't Upload Image!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Image Uploaded Succesfully!";
    echo json_encode($response);

/*
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($image_name);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($path);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_POST['username']);
*/

   }
    }   
?>
```

---

### As an `INSERT` to also insert the username entered, use the following, which will enter 3 values.

```
<?php
require('admin.config.inc.php');

$username=$_POST['username'];

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $path = "/home/********/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";

    if($image_name==''){
    echo "Don't just click! select an image please .";
    exit();
    }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $path);
    $mysql_path = $path."/".$image_name;

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `admin_test_so` (`user`,`admin_image1`,`path1`) VALUES (:user,:image_name,:mysql_path)");

    try {

 $stmt->execute(array(
  ':user' => $username,
  ':image_name' => $image_name,
  ':mysql_path' => $path

    ));


}
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't Upload Image!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Image Uploaded Succesfully!";
    echo json_encode($response);

/*
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($image_name);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($path);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_POST['username']);
*/

   }
    }   
?>
```

---

### HTML form

```
<form action="adminProfilePic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
<input type="file" name="image" >
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're try to bind `:image_name` and `:mysql_path`, but you insert it directly into the query. Change `$image_name` to `:image_name` and `$mysql_path` to `:mysql_path`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `admin`(`admin_image1`,`path1`) VALUES (:image_name',:mysql_path) where username = :user";

    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':image_name' => $image_name,
        ':mysql_path' => $path,
    );
```

Comment: Hi @Marcel, thanks for telling! I tried your suggestion but got the same error. The error seems to occur when I execute the query. It says "Database error. Couldn't upload image". anyway, does my form looks right? I kinda' doubt it.

Comment: But you've got a database connection?

Comment: Seems like it's the path method you're using, which is an absolute path. Try a relative path. I.e.: Instead of `$path = "/home/********/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";` 
use `$path = "StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name";` if running script from the root. If not from the root, then you may need to adjust using `../../StagConnect.....` @IamMe.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am running the script from a domain and I think that it's not the problem cause from my other forms the path works just fine.

Comment: Well, if you're running your code and you're not getting passed `Database error. Couldn't upload image` then the error/issue lies in and around there. @IamMe.

Comment: Can you try removing the comma in `':mysql_path' => $path,` @IamMe. Sometimes having a comma for the last entry, causes problems. I've seen it happen before.

Comment: Yet I think this `':mysql_path' => $path,` should be `':mysql_path' => $path,$mysql_path,` @IamMe. since that is the VALUE you're trying to pass/bind.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove the comma. thanks for pointing that out! anyway, it doesn't help neither. I'm thinking that maybe my form doesn't work since I have placed a textbox there while I'm using an enctype on my form. what do you think? @Fred-ii-

Comment: The enctype shouldn't get in the way of the text element. @IamMe.